# Without using CSC or Nuget, is it possible to use Powershell to add a reference to another project?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have a library that I need added to 10 other projects in my solution. It's not on Nuget, and it's only local on my machine.

Is there a Powershell approach (similar to Nuget `Install-package` ) that will allow me to add a specific reference to several *.csproj files?

Answer (score 0):

When you can create an .net-based assembly of your reference, you can add it simply with

```
Import-Module c:\path\to\your\assembly.dll
```

Using the assembly looks like this:

Example Usual Class:

```
$var = New-Object [Your.Namespace]::Classname(Constructor Arguments)
```

Example Static Class:

```
$var = [Your.Namespace]::Class.Method(Arguments)
```

Hope, this helps...

Edit: It seems, i've misunderstood your problem :(. Sorry about that.

Greetings, Ronny

Answer (score 0):

I think one approach would be to create a nuget package for your library, store it on your local drive in a specific directory, add that directory to your package sources, then open the Package Manager Console from your solution and issue a:

```
Get-Project -All | Install-Package <your package name>
```